# Prove that the limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to 4}{\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{x-4}} = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I was asked to prove, using the definition of limit, that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 4}{\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{x-4}} = \frac{1}{4}$$

I tried doing it but I am not completely sure my prove is correct. I am publishing it here so that more knowledgeable people can check it for me, maybe pointing any pitfalls.

I need to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < \left|x - 4\right| < \delta$ then $\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{x-4} - \frac{1}{4}\right| < \epsilon$

**First part: Tying to find a suitable $\delta$, given an $\epsilon$**

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{x-4} - \frac{1}{4}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{4(\sqrt{x}-2) - (x-4)}{4(x-4)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{4\sqrt{x} - 8 - x + 4}{4(x-4)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{4\sqrt{x} - x - 4}{4(x-4)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{-x + 4\sqrt{x} - 4}{4(x-4)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{-(x - 2\cdot\sqrt{x}\cdot 2 + 4)}{4(x-4)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{-(\sqrt{x} - 2)^2}{4(\sqrt{x}+2)(\sqrt{x}-2)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{-(\sqrt{x} - 2)}{4(\sqrt{x}+2)}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|-\frac{1}{4}\right| \left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{\sqrt{x}+2}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\frac{1}{4} \left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{\sqrt{x}+2}\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{\sqrt{x}+2}\right| < 4\epsilon$$
$$-4\epsilon < \frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{\sqrt{x}+2} < 4\epsilon$$

First inequation:
$$-4\epsilon < \frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{\sqrt{x}+2}$$
Multiplying by $\sqrt{x} + 2$ (which is positive):
$$-4\epsilon (\sqrt{x}+2) < \sqrt{x} - 2$$
$$-4\epsilon \sqrt{x} -8\epsilon < \sqrt{x} - 2$$
$$ - 8\epsilon + 2 < \sqrt{x} + 4\epsilon \sqrt{x}$$
$$ 2(1 - 4\epsilon) < (1 + 4\epsilon) \sqrt{x}$$
$$ \frac{2(1 - 4\epsilon)}{1+4\epsilon} < \sqrt{x}$$
$$ \left[\frac{2(1 - 4\epsilon)}{1+4\epsilon}\right]^2 < (\sqrt{x})^2$$
$$ \frac{4(1 - 4\epsilon)^2}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} < x$$
$$ \frac{4(1 - 4\epsilon)^2}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} - 4 < x - 4$$
$$ 4\left[\frac{(1 - 4\epsilon)^2}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} - 1\right] < x - 4$$
$$ 4\left[\frac{(1 - 4\epsilon)^2 - (1 + 4\epsilon)^2}{(1+4\epsilon)^2}\right] < x - 4$$
$$ 4\left[\frac{1 - 8\epsilon + 16\epsilon^2 - 1 - 8\epsilon - 16\epsilon^2}{(1+4\epsilon)^2}\right] < x - 4$$
$$ 4\left[\frac{-16\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2}\right] < x - 4$$
$$ \frac{-72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} < x - 4$$

Second inequation:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{\sqrt{x}+2} < 4\epsilon$$
Multiplying by $\sqrt{x} + 2$ (which is positive):
$$\sqrt{x} - 2 < 4\epsilon (\sqrt{x}+2)$$
$$\sqrt{x} - 2 < 4\epsilon \sqrt{x} + 8\epsilon$$
$$\sqrt{x} - 4\epsilon \sqrt{x} < 8\epsilon + 2$$
$$ (1 - 4\epsilon) \sqrt{x} < 2(1 + 4\epsilon)$$
$$\sqrt{x} <  \frac{2(1 + 4\epsilon)}{1-4\epsilon}$$
$$(\sqrt{x})^2 <  \left[\frac{2(1 + 4\epsilon)}{1-4\epsilon}\right]^2$$
$$x <  \frac{4(1 + 4\epsilon)^2}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}$$
$$x - 4 < \frac{4(1 + 4\epsilon)^2}{(1-4\epsilon)^2} - 4$$
$$x - 4 < 4\left[\frac{(1 + 4\epsilon)^2}{(1-4\epsilon)^2} - 1\right]$$
$$x - 4 < 4\left[\frac{(1 + 4\epsilon)^2 - (1 - 4\epsilon)^2}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}\right]$$
$$x - 4 < 4\left[\frac{1 + 8\epsilon + 16\epsilon^2 - 1 + 8\epsilon - 16\epsilon^2}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}\right]$$
$$x - 4 < 4\left[\frac{16\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}\right]$$
$$x - 4 < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}$$

Therefore:
$$- \frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} < x - 4 < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}$$

Taking the minimum of $\frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2}$ and $\frac{72\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}$ as the value for $\delta$:

$$ \delta = \min\left[\frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} , \frac{72\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}\right]$$
$$ \delta = \frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2}$$

**Second part: Prove**

Prove that

$$ 0 < \left|x-4\right| < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} \implies \left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{x-4} - \frac{1}{4}\right| < \epsilon$$

Is it correct so far? How to proceed from here?

Comment: Enjoy reading through that, "show your work" enthusiasts.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x} + 2$ and cancel. This will make your work a lot easier. Next make the a priori restriction $\delta \le 1$. Therefore you can additionally assume that $3 \le x \le 5$. Now look for a $\delta$.

Comment: i think the proof could be shortened  by making a change of variable from $x$ to $u$ with $x = 4 + u.$

Comment: I did, @GitGud. Just like grading a freshman calculus exam :-)

Comment: -1 for the amount of effort spent. Not that effort is a bad thing, but spending that much effort on a problem this straightforward is an indication that one is either doing it wrong or getting into too many unnecessary details.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Now,

$$0 < \left|x-4\right| < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} \implies  \frac{-72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} < x-4 < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2}$$

But: $$\frac{72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}$$

Hence:

$$\frac{-72\epsilon}{(1+4\epsilon)^2} < x-4 < \frac{72\epsilon}{(1-4\epsilon)^2}$$

I am sure you can proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt x -2}{x-4}=\frac{\sqrt x -2}{(\sqrt x -2)(\sqrt x +2)}$$

so

$$\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt x -2}{x-4}=\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{1}{\sqrt x +2}=\frac 14$$

Comment: @downvoter, why? If this is incorrect, please tell me why.

Comment: (I am not the down voter) Maybe because it was asked to prove using the definition of limit, not the properties.

Comment: Good point. Apologies if this answer is wrong.